Error in building project - babel module not found
I have been attempting to build and upload my project to PyPI with GitHub workflows, when an error occurs in this build section:

Here is the error itself:
File "/home/runner/work/crossword_puzzle/crossword_puzzle/crossword_puzzle/main.py", line 15, in <module>
from babel import Locale, UnknownLocaleError
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'babel'

The same issue happens with tox whenever I commit and GitHub workflows runs it to check the code. The same also happens when using tox directly on my computer.
This error wasn't happening before, and since I haven't changed anything major that would affect this in particular, I have no clue what to do.
Any suggestions or fixes?

DO NOT USE tag [python-3.x] UNLESS YOUR QUESTION IS FOR PYTHON 3 ONLY. Always use alongside the standard [python] tag.

By chance, I found out the issue.
In my main __init__.py, I defined the version like so:
__version__ = "1.2.81"

In the setup.py I imported it for use in the setup function
from crossword_puzzle import __version__

When this line was removed, the error no longer was raised by tox.
